# How do I disable Virtual Consoles tty[1-6]?

Tags: tty

How do I disable switching to virtual terminals (TTYs) using(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>) in  Ubuntu?

Comment: I guess you should take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/27975/157741) to *How can I reduce the number of TTYs?*

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want this? I've got a set of ill-behaved init-scripts that have somehow disabled these and am trying to *restore* them!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found three methods. I'm listing to help others if they need:

#### First Method:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/init/tty{1..6}.override <<<"manual"
```

#### Second Method:

Open/create the file [`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/xorg.conf.5.html) using the following command:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add the following lines inside:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

#### Third Method:

```
sudo -i

vi /etc/default/console-setup
```

change `ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"` to your choice. Lets say if you want only two TTY or virtual console then change to `ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-2]"`

```
cd /etc/event.d
```

Comment on all the lines in `ttyX` file that you don't need. In this example `tty3-tty6`
Reboot to see the change.

Answer (score 17):

Open/create the file [`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/xorg.conf.5.html) using the following command:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add the following lines inside:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

Source: [[all variants] How to disable CTRL ALT F1 - ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=776098)

Comment: Note that once in a while, when X11 gets stuck, those keys allow you to get out to a console and cleaning shutdown your system... I used that many times although these days I have a lot less problems with X11 getting stuck!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm /etc/init/tty*.conf
```

This will totally remove the `tty* conf` file and thus you will not be able to use it :)

NB: you can't be able to restore it later on

Answer (score 0):

open the tty conf in the `/etc/init/` directory

comment out those lines in the ttyX.conf files:

```
#respawn 
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 ttyX
```

Example to disable tty1:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

Then edit by inserting # in front of the commands

```
#respawn 
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Save and Reboot

Answer (score 0):

On Gnome Wayland you can unset the keybindings for virtual terminal switching by setting these dconf properties:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-1 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-2 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-3 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-4 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-5 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-6 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-7 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-8 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-9 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-10 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-11 "['']"
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-12 "['']"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be disabled in dconf-editor too:

1. Search "switch-to-session", in dconf-editor;
2. Select each item of "switch-to-session-1" to "switch-to-session-12";
3. For each item, turn off "Use default value", and set "Custom value" to "[]";

Search in dconf-editor:

[image: search in dconf-editor]

Set custom value for each item:

[image: set Custom value for each item]