# Is it possible to change user while logged in as guest?

Tags: 14.04, permissions

before my first few questions, let me begin with a background story(tl;dr below):

So, I'm setting up some new computers at my workplace for public access and I had the bright idea(and I still think it is) to install ubuntu on them. I have about 2 weeks of experience with 'linux and friends' as of today and I'm at least a little proud of what I've achieved, but I'm at a loss right now as I can't find solutions to my problems. I want to make all regular users invisible, one already is(the template-user for the guest), so there's only the guest-account to choose from.
I want this for numerous reasons, we run an big indoor playground, so a lot of nosy kids and dumbfound parents(of which 99% are indoctrinated with windows... like me) will be using these computers. Limiting their choices will mean less questions, which is good, since no one other than me will be able to answer, and I ain't there all of the time.

**TL;DR-ish:**

So this is what I'm wondering:

*If all regular users are invisible, and since guest has no privileges, how do I log in to them if I need to change anything? (I don't want manual login-screen)*

**More relevant info/thoughts:** invisibility is setup by editing /var/lib/AccountsService/users/*user-file* and changing SystemAccount=false to true. I've skimmed by something saying you could set userid below 1000 to achieve the same result, would this method change anything regarding my problem, you know, like making it easier?
Can I do something from the TTY? (what ever that is, it really confuses me, what separates it from the normal Ctrl+Alt+T terminal?)
Maybe I'm going at this the wrong way, is there a boot-menu or something I could use to gain access? And if so, can I block little potential junior hackers from using it?

Hope that helps you help me, if there's something unclear or something you need to know, just ask away. :)

Comment: what is that thing you call TTF ?

Comment: @solsTiCe I think he means TTY.

Comment: Yeah, I meant TTY, fixed it now to avoid more confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to choose **strong** password with at least 16 characters.

**TTY** or *console* is just a non graphical terminal.

*guest* is a restricted account with limited privileges and you can't `sudo` with that account.

Your only option if you have disabled the other admin account on the login screen, is to switch to a console (aka use `ctrl-alt-f1`) and do your administration work there. This will mean using only the command line, so you need to improve your *cli-fu* to be fluent with it.

Mainly you need to know `apt-get`, `dpkg`, `apt-cache`, `apt-file`, `nano`

## Disable TTYs

And you can disable ttys also, but then the only way to administer the PC will be via **ssh** (if it is connected to a LAN), given you have installed and configured *openssh-server* correctly.

- [Disable the ability to switch to TTYs (Ctrl+Alt+F1…F6)](https://askubuntu.com/q/357039/350004)
- [How can I reduce the number of TTYs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/27967/350004)

Comment: Thanks for the great info, can I use the console and TTY for the same stuff? Given I have full privileges for the user I'm logged in as for the console. Does the TTY not care about the current users privileges?

I assume you use "cli-fu" as a slang of sorts to indicate I need to familiarize myself with client commands, or is it a thing?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/196/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Linux!

I have a very hacky and inelegant way that might work:

1. Go to the TTY by typing for instance `Ctr+Alt+F1`
2. Login as the user you would like to switch to (administrator)
3. Type the command `startx` to start the GUI of this user
4. Then, once in this session (`Ctr+Alt+F8`), open a terminal by pressing `Ctr+Alt+T`
5. Type `unity` to restart unity.

It will still be a bit buggy but it worked for me.

Comment: A thought, could I access TTY from the login-screen? (Don't have access to the computers as I have them at home and are at work right now, might seem a bit backwards, but my role at this company is not related to computers)
And if so, could I figure out and launch the same commands as lightDM to login as the user I want?

Comment: You can of course access TTY from the login-screen, but if you start or restart lightdm from like that it will bring you back to the  login-screen and not in the wanted user session. At least under usual configuration of lightdm.