# Uninstall terminal

Tags: command-line, system-installation, package-management, dpkg

I ask here, because googling about is quite chaotic (you fall to 'how to uninstall *via* terminal).

I wonder how to uninstall terminal ? *Cause I want to add some hardness in playing with a delivered machine*

Comment: I'm confused why you want to remove terminal...?

Comment: do you try to uninstall a terminal program (like xterm) or are you trying to uninstall a program using a terminal (using the command line interface)???

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Comment: The package name is `gnome-terminal`, you might also want to remove `xterm`. And `getty`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Virtual Consoles tty\[1..6\]](http://askubuntu.com/questions/357039/disable-virtual-consoles-tty1-6)

Answer (score 2):

The terminal used by default is Gnome Terminal. There are 2 ways to uninstall it.

1. Command line method:

   Open `tty1` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
   ```

   It will be removed.
2. Graphical method:

   Open the Software Centre and search for Gnome Terminal:

   [image]

   Click the first result called "Terminal (gnome-terminal)" and click remove.