# Ubuntu : Disable access to file-manager, keyboard,mouse(Touch screen available) for guest account

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, nautilus, security, touchscreen

I am looking to configure Ubuntu(Any version, new installation) for presentation in which I would like to do the following things :

1. Automatic guest-login at startup.
2. Completely disable keyboard,mouse, USB ports, there is a touch-screen available which the user can use.
3. Disable TTY access i.e ctrl+alt+F2,F3, and so on.
4. No access to file-system via nautilus.

I can just purge nautilus simply to complete the 4th point, if there is any other decent approach, kindly let me know.

Suggestions for any points or more security are always welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95405/how-to-enable-guest-account-automatic-login). That should do the trick
2. `lsmod | grep usb` to list all usb modules being loaded right now and then unload these modules with `sudo rmmod usb_whatever`
3. look here [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357039/disable-virtual-consoles-tty1-6). But keep in mind, that if you disable that, it could lead to problems if the X-Server is not starting.
4. I think that is not needed because the guest has no right to see other files than its. But even if you disable nautilus or something else for the guest user, s/he can always use the terminal to navigate through the files. But purging the file manager would be the easiest way to reach that goal, i guess. Else, find the group that manages the access for nautilus and kick guest out off it.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I will be starting Firefox in full-screen anyways at startup. Is there any way to disable terminal access as well for guest user?

Comment: No, that will make every Linux useless.

Comment: I meant only for guest. But yes, that would mean disabling bash, is also the point I get. But Terminal end of the day is an independent software.

Comment: Okay, yes, maybe. Than like number 4 -> find the group and kick guest out.

Comment: find the group and kick guest out : Didn't understood this part.

Comment: Everything in *nix systems is being done by group and user rights. So if you want to start a webbrowser from your account you need to be in the group that manages the webbrowser access. Please see some guides for further information and read some wikis for Linux basics

Comment: That I know, I just couldn't figure out how terminal is connected to groups. It's okay, I will find it. Thank you for your answer.. :-)