# 15.10 update/login problem

Tags: 15.10

While updating my Ubuntu desktop to the 15.10 update the computer froze and then got shut off. When I turned it back on a message shows up every time saying,

Ubuntu 15.10 primary-HP-Compaq-dc7600-Small-Form-Factor tty1

primary-HP-Compaq-dc7600-Small-Form-Factor login:

Password:

Answer (score 0):

You can find all about what tty means in here: [What does "TTY" stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for).

Basically, it is a CLI (command-line) interface, simple text only. Just enter your password. If that doesn't work, type: `sudo su` and enter the root password. Then type `startx`. A graphical interface should appear. If it doesn't, probably, something went wrong with the update. Type `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` to redo the update.

Comment: login: sudo su       Password: prim@ry startx       is this what i am supposed to do. if i press Ctrl+Alt+F7 a GUI will show but if i type anything, nothing will show up.