# Alt +F1 shortcut that makes me pick my user again - how to disable it

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Today morning something strange has happened and suddenly <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut takes me to the screen where I have to pick my user - I don't have to put my password again and every windows is still opened. I's not like locking up my computer with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, where I still have to put my password.

It's very strange because I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> every day many many times (IntelliJ shortcut) and it has never happened.

Any ideas how can I disable it? It's nowhere to be found in Shortcuts in Settings.

Comment: Huh, it does not actuall. Thank you a lot! Curious what might have happened...

Comment: What Ubuntu version you have, 18.04, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F#</kbd> switches through the [TTYs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for).

<kbd>F1</kbd> switches to the X session with the display manager (`gdm`) running the login screen.
<kbd>F2</kbd> switches to the first logged in user,
<kbd>F3</kbd> switches to the second logged in user,
... and so on.

This makes you easily switch between logged in users on a multi-user system.
Any TTY where no user is logged in will run a console (text) TTY.

When you go to `gdm` (<kbd>F1</kbd>) and log in, you will automatically be sent back to the TTY you are already logged in (in your case probably TTY-2).

Try it, you can always switch back to your "normal" session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

---

In older versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 16.04), X was running on TTY7 per default (<kbd>F7</kbd>) and the display manager `lightdm` was not on a separate TTY.