# Ctrl+Alt+F7 doesn't switch back to X session in Kubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, tty, sddm

After I switch to virtual console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> I could not get back to X session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> - only blinking cursor is shown. Tried `chvt` - same result. Have to reboot and lost all my opened apps which is very inconvenient. Kubuntu version is 18.04 Bionic.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Other as [in Ubuntu 17.10 and later](https://askubuntu.com/a/979029/507051), in Kubuntu 18.04 the default display manager is SDDM, where:

- `tty1` holds the GUI session
  get there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or (`sudo`) `chvt 1`
- `tty2` to `tty6` hold non-graphical TTY sessions
  get there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> or (`sudo`) `chvt 2` to `chvt 6`
- `tty7` and above are unused

Further reading:

- [How can I reduce the number of TTYs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/27967/507051) (also answers how to *increase* their number)
- [SDDM bug report from 2014](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/317) about this, which also contains a workaround to make SDDM start on `tty7`

Comment: What's the logic in needing `sudo` for actions that can be done with an unprivileged keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @EricDuminil At least I need `sudo` to run `chvt` from a normal terminal session, else `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: A remote user or unprivileged daemon account cannot press keys on your keyboard. Pressing something on the keyboard conveys a high level of privilege: you're physically present and thus capable of taking over the machine in any number of physical ways.

Answer (score 4):

On a [Linux text-mode virtual console / terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console), **Alt+left-arrow and Alt+right-arrow cycle through virtual consoles.**

(X servers disable that keybind, so switch to a text-mode VC first, with ctrl+alt+f2, or any VC number that doesn't have an X session running on it.

If you're ever not sure which VC something is on, or which VTs exist, use one of those to cycle through and see what you find.  If there's an X session running on a VC, you will find it.